# AS3 - disable all buttons except one

Tags: actionscript-3

During an upload I need to disable all buttons on stage except the one to cancel the upload process.
I tried this but "mybutton" keeps on being disabled:

```
stage.mouseChildren = false;
mysection.mybutton.mouseChildren = true
```

How to do it?

Comment: Setting `mouseChildren` to `false` will suppress all mouse events originating from any child of the particular `DisplayObject`. When you apply this to the `stage`, you're effectively suppressing *all* mouse events in your entire SWF. You'll need to explicitly disable the necessary buttons, or find a way to group them so that you can disable them in one call.

Comment: You can't have THAT many buttons, why don't just disable them one by one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Somthing like below might help you. but you have to check for syntax errors, dont have time for checks... Ask any question if you cant sort out.

```
function findMyButton(doc:DisplayObjectContainer , n:String):void{
  for(var i:int=0; i<doc.numChildren; i++)
  {
    var btn:DisplayObjectContainer = this.getChildAt(i) as DisplayObjectContainer;

    if(btn && btn.numChildren > 0){
       findMyButton(btn , n);
    }

      if(btn.name =="btn_upload")
      {
        btn.mouseEnabled = true;
      }
      else
      {
        btn.mouseEnabled = false;
      }

  }

}

// This ll allow you to disable or enable all your objects
// so you can activate the button you like after you call this method.
function conrolmyButtons(doc:DisplayObjectContainer , b:Boolean):void{
  for(var i:int=0; i<doc.numChildren; i++)
  {
    var btn:DisplayObjectContainer = this.getChildAt(i) as DisplayObjectContainer;
    if(btn && btn.numChildren > 0){
       findMyButton(btn , n);
    }
    btn.mouseEnabled = b;
  }

}
```

Comment: Your code is Wrong.
DisplayObject can not have any children.
In other words. do.numchildren<<< is Incorrect.
Are You UnderStand DisplayObject Layer Inheritance?
running your own code that you'll notice the crappy code.

Comment: SimpleButton is InteractiveObejct.

InteractiveObject also can not have any children...

var btn:DisplayObjectContainer = this.getChildAt(i) as DisplayObjectContainer; <<< what's the mean?

perhaps btn is simplebutton. so, why you forced convert SimpleButton to DisplayObjectContainer??? you're code not available...

Comment: Is there any mention that the buttons are SimpleButton? i cant see any information about it.